# apache proxying requests to tomcat

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat

I have put the following in my apache conf

```
    ProxyPass /manager http://localhost:8080/manager/
    ProxyPassReverse /manager http://localhost:8080/manager/

    ProxyPass /foo http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse /foo http://localhost:8080/
```

However when I go to either of those links I get a 403 forbidden page.

However, if I simply go to my http://mysite.com:8080  that works fine.
To actually get to my manager I actually seem to have to go to http://mysite.com:8080/manager/html  however I have also tried

```
    ProxyPass /manager http://localhost:8080/manager/html
    ProxyPassReverse /manager http://localhost:8080/manager/html
```

and that hasn't worked eithter

Any thoughts?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at a reverse proxy we have defined here, it looks like you need to define:

```
  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>
```

In the same Virtual Host container.

Comment: Woohoo -- thanks so much.  Been banging my head against this one for a while!

Comment: No problem, glad that was all you needed. :)